# How do I input SQL Database information into a php table

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, database

I have both the Database information inputted which includes a team logo and the corresponding team name.
Despite various google searches and forum searching, I cannot find a solution.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php
  $connection = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","");
  mysqli_select_db($connection,"6nationsDB");
  $result=mysqli_query($connection,"select * from teams");
$counter = 1;
  while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
    $image="images/$counter.png";
    print"<img src=\"$image\" width=\"15px\" height=\"15px\"\/>";
    print($row['name']);

    print("<br>");


    $counter++;
  }

  $rows = 10; // amout of tr 
$cols = 10;// amjount of td 
function drawTable($rows, $cols){
echo "<table border='1'>"; 

for($tr=1;$tr<=$rows;$tr++){ 

    echo "<tr>"; 
        for($td=1;$td<=$cols;$td++){ 
               echo "<td align='center'>".'<img src=\"$image\" width=\"15px\" height=\"15px\"\/>'."</td>"; 

        }

    echo "</tr>"; 
} 
echo "</table>";

}
drawTable(6, 2);
  mysqli_close($connection);
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How is the structure of your table? What types do the columns have? :-)
If you could provide an example tuple it would help aswell.

Comment: What are you trying to do here? A PHP Table? What is that? Do you mean an HTML TABLE element? ;) Also, that code is quite the mess to try and follow what you are wanting to do, without any examples of what you WANT it to do. Why are you printing images before echoing the table...

Comment: have you tried googling "mysqli php example"? the first link is to the PHP manual and it provides some pretty good examples